# parallel sections with boost

Tags: c++, boost, openmp

I'm looking for a way to use boost threads to run chunks of code in parallel without creating worker functions or functors. I'd like something similar to OpenMP's parallel sections construct:

```
#pragma omp parallel sections
{
   #pragma omp section
   {
      ... do some work
   }
   #pragma omp section
   {
      ... do some more
   }
}
```

Is there a way to accomplish this using boost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use C++11, *lambda* expression will be useful. (lambda is actually a sort of functor, but following code looks like OpenMP version?)

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

{
  boost::thread th1([&]() {
    // ... do some work (thread#1)
  });
  boost::thread th2([&]() {
    // ... do some more (thread#2)
  });
  // wait for two tasks completion
  th1.join();
  th2.join();
}
```

Or `thread_group` version:

```
{
  boost::thread_group pool;
  pool.create_thread([&]() {
    // ... do some work (thread#1)
  });
  pool.create_thread([&]() {
    // ... do some more (thread#2)
  });
  // wait for two tasks completion
  pool.join_all();
}
```